# Удалить лишние пробелы из строки

Tags: python, строки

Не работает. Ошибка. В чем проблема?

---

```
kio = "dfgh     sdfgdfg dfgfgdf    dfgdfg"
print type(kio)
kio.replace('\n', '')
print kio
```

Comment: Так вы что удалить пытаетесь-то? Переводы строк что ли? А они есть?

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Как удалить все пробелы из строки в Python?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/359110/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-python)

Answer (score 10):

```
>>> t = "x    fe  a"
>>> t.split()
['x', 'fe', 'a']
>>> ' '.join(t.split())
'x fe a'
```

Answer (score 9):

ваш код

```
kio = "dfgh     sdfgdfg dfgfgdf    dfgdfg"
print kio.replace('\n', '')
```

правильно так. но он удалит переводы строк а не пробелы.
если вам нужно удалить вообще все пробельные символы (включая переводы строк и табуляцию):

```
import re
print re.sub(r'\s', '', kio)
```

если нужно удалить только лишние пробелы (оставить один)

```
re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', kio)
```