# Как удалить все пробелы из строки в Python?

Tags: python, функции

Нагуглил функцию `strip()`, но она удаляет только первый и последний пробел, а мне нужно все.
Например, если `a = ' sd dfsdf  dfsfs'`, то нужно получить `a = 'sddfsdfdfsfs'`.
Есть ли такая функция или надо через цикл как-то делать?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
a.replace(' ', '')
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую.

Answer (score 14):

`strip()` может удалить не только пробел, но и табы и другие символы, которые считаются пробелом, включая Юникодные пробелы, если `strip()` вызван для Юникодной строки:

```
>>> import string
>>> string.whitespace
'\t\n\x0b\x0c\r '
>>> string.whitespace.strip()
''
>>> import sys
>>> s = ''.join(unichr(i) for i in xrange(sys.maxunicode) if unichr(i).isspace())
>>> s[:15]
u'\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f \x85\xa0\u1680\u180e\u2000'
>>> s.strip()
u''
```

Поэтому аналог `strip()`, который удаляет пробел во всей строке: `s = ''.join(s.split())`.

Или, тоже самое, используя регулярные выражения:  `s = re.sub(r'\s+', '', s, flags=re.UNICODE)`.

Или, в коде, где важна производительность, `bytes.translate()` может быть использован, чтобы удалить все стандартные (`string.whitespace` в С локале) пробелы из ascii строки:

```
>>> b'a\tb\nc'.translate(None, b'\t\n\v\f\r ')
'abc'
```

Answer (score 5):

Если неизвестно количество пробелов, и табов, самый простой способ:

```
a = 'Some        string   with    meny          space or tabs'

b = a.split()
b = ''.join(b)

b >>> Somestringwithmenyspaceortabs
```