# Узнать образуют ли введённые слова палиндром

Tags: python, алгоритм

Итак, есть задача и вот её условие:

> На вход подается единственная строка, состоящая из слов, разделенных пробелами. Выведите YES, если после перестановки всех слов строки в обратном порядке получается та же строка, и NO в противном случае.

Например, если вбить

> so patient a doctor to doctor a patient so

то программа выведет YES

Для решения задачи я составил алгоритм:

1. вводится строка;
2. создается новая строка по следующему принципу:

   2.1. все слова искомой строки, не считая последней, идут вперед, т.е. ставятся перед первой. Пример: последнее слово имеет номер n, тогда слово n-1 ставится перед n, слово n-2 ставят перед n-1 и т.д.;

   2.2. у полученной строки не должно быть пробелов, т.е. все символы стоят в плотную;
3. у искомой и получившейся строки удаляются все пробелы и затем они сравниваются. Вот собственно и все.

Проблем с реализацией 1-го и 3-го пункта у меня нет, а вот как реализовать 2-й, я пока не понимаю. Прошу помочь.

Comment: @Hashirama, зачем так сложно?

1. Строка разбивается на слова (метод `.split()`, если не ошибаюсь)
2. Полученный массив переворачивается.
3. Создается новая строка и сравнивается с оригинальной либо перевернутый массив сравнивается с оригинальным.

Comment: Почему так сложно? Не знаю, могу выделить две причины:

1) я не знаком с "инструментами", с помощью которых можно проще;  
2) тупо не могу догадаться до более простого метода.

Поясните, что Вы подразумеваете под "переворачиванием" массива.

Comment: Эмъ... Может быть:

    txt = 'so patient a doctor to doctor a patient so'
    txt_arr = txt.split('\s')
    txt_arr_reverse = list(txt_arr)
    txt_arr_reverse.reverse()
    print 'YES' if txt_arr == txt_arr_reverse else 'NO'

Т.е. преобразовали в массив, сделали копию массива и сравнили исходный массив и перевернутую копию - если равны, значит все ОК.

Так пойдет?

Comment: Да, но поясните, что делает вторая строка Вашего кода. И четвертая.

Comment: 2 строка разбивает текст на массив слов по разделителю (у меня там ошибка, сейчас исправлю).  
4 строка переворачивает массив.

Лучше запустите и посмотрите, что происходит, сами.

Comment: @BOPOH,

    txt_arr = txt.split(' ')
    txt_arr_reverse = list(txt_arr)

Вообще-то split и так в результате дает список.

Comment: @insolor, а вас не смущает следующее:

    a = [1, 2, 3]
    b = a
    a[0] = 3 # <- a = [3, 2, 3], b = [3, 2, 3]
    b[1] = 3 # <- a = [3, 3, 3], b = [3, 3, 3]

Если не заметили, далее я сравниваю txt_arr и txt_arr_reverse. Чтобы txt_arr_reverse.reverse() так же не менял и txt_arr (а значит сравнение было бы бесполезным) я и использую клонирование списка (т.е. list от списка)

UPD: avp, а кто спорит? У любой задачи есть если не куча, то хотя бы несколько решений, взять хотя бы swap. Даже для вашего варианта есть несколько способов реализации. Я же просто привел один из способов.

Comment: @BOPOH, тут вообще не нужны 2 списка. Достаточно одного. Просто сравниваете слова с начала списка со словами в его же конце.

Comment: @BOPOH, тогда вот так, без дополнительной переменной: txt_arr == list(reversed(txt_arr)). А вообще, конечно, способов реализации довольно много.

Comment: Комментарии появились ))

@insolor, да кто же спорит? Я могу кучу вариаций привести (с различными if`ами только несколько штук), здесь сама идея важна - я ее на конкретном примере и показал.

А вообще - я комментарием выше про это уже писал.

Если же вы про мой ответ вам, то я ваш комментарий понял буквально - "txt_arr уже список, поэтому list(txt_arr) можно заменить на txt_arr". Но ведь в данном случае работа алгоритма сломается, на что я и указал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def validate(string):
    return "YES" if string == " ".join(string.split()[::-1]) else "NO"
print validate("so patient a doctor to doctor a patient so")
```

Есть как минимум 2 способа инвертировать строку/массив без зауми:

- reversed(iterable) -> generator object
- iterable[::-1] -> инвертированный массив/строка

Тогда задача сводится к простому набору шагов:

- разбить строку на слова (.split() или .split(" ") или можно регулярками)
- инвертировать получившийся массив
- склеить обратно через пробел (" ".join(iterable))
- просто сравнить строки и если True, то вернуть YES, иначе вернуть NO
- профит

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы проверить, образуют ли данные слова палиндром на Питоне:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
def is_palindrome(seq):
    return seq == seq[::-1]

words = input('Введите слова, разделённые пробелом: ').split()
print("YES" if is_palindrome(words) else "NO")
```

Особенности:

- `.split()` используется вместо `.split(' ')` , чтобы исключить любые символы пробела.

Чтобы реализовать пункт 2. из вопроса, смотри: [Как удалить все пробелы из строки в Python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/359110/function-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-python)

Существуют алгоритмы, которые не требуют `.split()`, которые могут работать без дополнительной памяти, используя только исходную строку (O(1)-space): [Efficiently reverse the order of the words (not characters) in an array of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47402/4279).

Answer (score 1):

Может, лучше будет сравнивать слова друг с другом? Первое и последнее, второе и предпоследнее и так далее. Все слова равны - YES. Хотя бы одно не равно - NO. Есть и другие варианты. Но это так, я, в общем-то, питон не учил, но полагаю, там так можно.

Comment: Вы на пример внимательно посмотрите. С чем в таком случае сравнивать "to"?

Comment: Само с собой сравнится. Не волнуйся, прокатит. Выше господин указывал на метод split(). Разбив им строку на слова, вполне можно будет их сравнить между собой.

Answer (score 0):

Задача называется поиск полиндромов.
Удалить все пробелы  
"String".replace(' ','')

Можно удалять не просто пробелы, но и все пробельные символы  (табуляцию и т.д.).
Для этого нужно изучить регулярные выражения и использовать мождуль re.

Comment: Удалять пробелы ни в коем случае нельзя. Иначе у вас неверно сработает строка 

so patient a doctor to doctor apatient so

Comment: А разве палиндром это "to be be to"? Я че-то думал, что "to be eb ot".

Comment: Ну, палиндром может быть как из букв ("abcd dcba"), так и из слов ("a1 a2 a2 a1"). ТС нужен палиндром из слов. Поэтому количество пробелов между словами роли не играет.

--

Определить, является ли строка палиндромом из букв, вообще очень просто (на Си)

     int is_palindrome (const char *s) {
         int i = 0, j = strlen(s);
     
         while (i < j)
          if (s[i++] != s[--j])
             return 0;
         return 1;
     }

Алгоритм для палиндрома из слов -- совершенно аналогичный, только надо передать массив слов и его размер и сравнивать слова, а не символы.