# Задача "Палиндром". Python

Tags: python

**Задача:**
По данной строке определите, является ли она палиндромом (то есть верно ли, что она одинаково читается слева направо и справа налево)

**Ввод**
На вход подается строка без пробелов. Длина строки не превышает 200. Буквы разного регистра считаются различными.

**Вывод**
Необходимо вывести yes, если строка является палиндромом, и no в противном случае.

**Пример:**

abba      yes

qwerq     no

```
slovo = str(input())
x = len(slovo)
i = 0
x = x - 1
k = 0
while x - i >= i:
    if slovo[x - i] == slovo[i]:
        i += 1
    else:
        k = 1
        break
if k == 1:
  print("no")
else:
  print("yes")
```

Неправильный ответ на 6 тесте. Я и понятие не имею какое слово это может быть.
Кто-то может придумает?

UPD: Тесты - это проверка моего кода на сайте. Программа подставляет в мой код разные слова и проверяет правильность моего решения. 5 слов - правильно. 6 тест - нет. Я не могу придумать такое слово и не знаю какое слово подставляла в этом тесте программа.

Comment: Огласите все тесты, а то вообще не понятно о чем речь?

Comment: Тесты - это система проверяет правильность моего кода. Я не знаю какие там тесты.

Comment: Ну так набейте самостоятельно несколько сотен строк, а то и тысяч (не руками, конечно же): заведомо палиндромов, заведомо не, да и гоняйте свой код по ним.

Comment: Не раз сталкивался, что на проверяющих системах тесты не соответствуют описанию. Поэтому вполне вероятно, что где-то в начале или в конце строки затесался пробел, или первая строка является пустой, а данные находятся во второй строке. Есть несколько вариантов решения проблемы: а) написать программу на языке, в котором все пробельные символы игнорируются при считывании (C++), б) написать заведомо простой (и, как следствие, завдомо верный) код на Python и отослать его, потому что Ваш код слишком перегружен для данной задачи. Соответственно, если вариант б) не решает задачу, то используем а)

Comment: Это проверяющая система Школы анализа данных Яндекса. В условии сказано - "без пробелов". Делал точно такую же задачу на другом сайте (informatics) - успешно прошли все 15 тестов. Как такое может быть?

Comment: Система открыта для внешнего использования? Можете дать ссылку, я попробую свой вариант решения на ней прогнать.

Comment: Нет уже все. Регистрация закончена.

Comment: @ValeryO, вы не можете ничего утверждать до тех пор, пока не увидите тестовые наборы данных для обоих случаев. Откуда вы знаете, что они "точно такие же"?

Comment: 1. Какая версия Питона используется на сайте проверок? 2. Показывает ли судья сообщения об ошибках, возникающие в проверяемой программе? 3. Напишите функцию `is_palindrome(word)` и потестируйте её на случайных данных (`os.urandom()`), сравнивая результаты с другими реализациями, например: [`def is_palindrome_seq(seq): return seq == seq[::-1]`](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/359777/23044)

Comment: 1) Python 3.2     2) Никаких ошибок. 5 тестов - успешно. 6-й тест не верен.

Comment: ValeryO, еще раз повторюсь - Ваше решение слишком сложно для задачи и для языка Python в целом. Возьмите вариант, предложенный @jfs и попробуйте его отправить. Если не пройдет - очень большая вероятность того, что в тестах ошибка. Система позволяет использовать другие языки программирования? Если нет, то попробуйте убирать все пробелы в начале и в конце строки, а также игнорировать пустые строки.

Comment: @ValeryO: мета: если информация может помочь в ответе на вопрос, то отредактируйте ваш вопрос вместо добавления комментариев.

Comment: @ValeryO: *свои* тесты *локально* следует запускать. В качестве входных данных можно использовать случайные строки, слова из словарей, слова с разной Юникодной нормализацей, пробовать пустый строки, слова из одной,2,3,4,5 букв, слова с разным регистром. Если разные реализации функции `is_palindrome(word)` возвращают одни и те же значения для всех типов ввода, то можно на сайт решение отправить.

Comment: Чтобы глубже свой код понять, полезно ещё код на [pythontutor.com отправить](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=slovo+%3D+str(input())%0Ax+%3D+len(slovo)%0Ai+%3D+0%0Ax+%3D+x+-+1%0Ak+%3D+0%0Awhile+x+-+i+%3E%3D+i%3A%0A++++if+slovo%5Bx+-+i%5D+%3D%3D+slovo%5Bi%5D%3A%0A++++++++i+%2B%3D+1%0A++++else%3A%0A++++++++k+%3D+1%0A++++++++break%0Aif+k+%3D%3D+1%3A%0A++print(%22no%22)%0Aelse%3A%0A++print(%22yes%22)&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&textReferences=false&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%22%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%22%5D&curInstr=1)

Comment: А нормально ли этот код реагирует на многобайтовые строки (т.е. UTF-8)? Все ли граничные задачи рассматриваются (пустая строка должна вернуть "нет", например)?

Comment: попробовал с кириллицей - валится.

Comment: @Etki: Автор использует Python 3, поэтому `input()` возвращает Unicode.

Comment: @KoVadim: если не рассматривать случаи, когда одна буква может быть представлена несколькими Юникодными символами (например, `'й'` (U+0438 U+0306)), то коду всё равно на каком языке буквы (он одинаково для всех Юникодных символов работает (или одинаково не работает)).

Answer (score 11):

Можно было еще просто сравнить исходное слово с ним же, но вывод наоборот [::-1]. На stepic.org была такая задача)
Я вот так решал эту задачу

```
slovo = str(input())
a = slovo[::-1]
if slovo == a:
  print("yes")
else:
  print("no")
```

Comment: можно сократить на одну строчку `if slovo == slovo[::-1]:`

Comment: в slovo = str(input()) str не нужен, оно строка по умолчанию

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in range(100,1000):
    for n in range(100,1000):
        number = str(n*i)
        if (number == number[::-1])and(int(number)>900000):
            palindromic = number
            break
print(palindromic)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Answer (score 1):

```
n = int(input("input n: "))
s = str(n) 
l = len(s)
for i in range(l//2):
    if s[i] != s[-1-i]: 
       print("It's not palindrome")
       break
else:
    print("It's palindrome")
```

Вот код как я розвязал в универе

Comment: Indentation Error

Comment: всьо получається

Comment: посмотри правильно ли ти скопировал

Comment: Будто там было возможно правильно скопировать

Comment: используй `enumerate` для доступа к ключу

Answer (score 1):

```
string = input('Введите слово: ')
string_reversed = reversed(string)
if "yes" == "".join(set(["yes" if i == j else "no" for i, j in zip(string, string_reversed)])):
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Comment: Ну вот зачем такие сложности, когда можно написать просто `if string == string[::-1]`?

Comment: Да вы правы) Просто наверное код зависит от уровня владения языком, я любитель.

Answer (score 1):

```
def palindrome(s: str):
    snew = s.replace(" ", "").lower()
    ls = len(snew)
    if snew[:ls // 2] == snew[ls // 2 + 1:][::-1]:
        return "Палиндром"
    return "Не палиндром"
```

Красивое решение и длину строки проверять не надо

Comment: `'aa'` -> `Не палиндром`.

Answer (score 0):

Такой вариант:

```py
s = input('Введите слово: ')
r = reversed(s)
ispal = True
for a in s[:len(s)//2]:
    if a != next(r):
        ispal = False
        break
print("yes" if ispal else "no")
```

Половина букв не проверяется, что быстрее.

Можно задействовать `all`:

```py
from operator import eq
s = input('Введите слово: ')
res = all(map(lambda x: eq(*x), zip(s, reversed(s))))
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

с тернарным оператором

```
a = input().lower()
b = a[::-1].lower()
print("палиндром" if b == a else "не палиндром")
```

с lower() приводит шрифт к нижнему регистру, без-проверяет только строгое соответствие, буквы в нижнем и верхнем регистре будут считаться разными