# Python, длина строки без учета пробелов

Tags: python

Как можно на Python получить длину строки, но чтобы не считались пробелы? К примеру, чтобы длина "99 99 99 99" равнялась длине "9999 9999"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Можно так: `len(str.replace(" ", ""))`

Answer (score 6):

Можно просто вычесть кол-во пробелов: `n = len(s) - s.count(" ")`.

Достоинство, что не требуется новую строку создавать: `O(1)` в памяти—для больших строк может иметь значение в производительности.

Если нужно поддерживать произвольные пробельные символы (перевод строки `'\n'`, таб `'\t'`, неразрывный пробел (U+00A0),  итд), то можно использовать регулярное выражение, чтобы посчитать кол-во непробельных символов в строке:

```
import re

n = len(re.findall(u"\\S", s, flags=re.UNICODE))
```

ответ близок к [`n  = len(''.join(s.split()))` или другому способу, основанному на удалении пробелов из строки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/359306/23044).

Можно избежать создания нового списка, если использовать `finditer()`:

```
n = sum(1 for m in re.finditer(u"\\S", s, flags=re.UNICODE) if m)
```

этот код требует `O(1)`памяти (константа независящая от размера входной строки), но на практике даже для умеренно больших строк он может быть медленнее  более жадных вариантов, где память пропорциональна вводу `O(n)` (решения, использующие список, новую строку).

Answer (score 4):

```
len(''.join("99 99 99 99".split()))
```

сравнение быстродействия способов:

```
import timeit, sys, itertools, re, random, string

def var1():
    return len([s for s in _str if not s == ' '])
def var2():
    return len(list(itertools.chain(*_str.split())))
def var3():
    return len(''.join(_str.split()))
def var4(ln=0):
    for с in _str:
        if с != ' ': ln += 1
    return ln
def var5():
    return sum(map(lambda c: int(not(c == ' ')) , _str))
def var6():
    return sum(map(lambda c: 1 if c != ' ' else 0, _str))
def var7():
    return len(_str.replace(" ", ""))
def var8():
    return len(_str) - _str.count(" ")
def var9():
    return len(re.findall(u"\\S", _str, flags=re.UNICODE))
def var10():
    return sum(1 for m in re.finditer(u"\\S", _str, flags=re.UNICODE) if m)


def print_results(data: dict):
    # печать результатов одного прохода
    x = ['average', 'min', 'max']
    f = ' {:<12}' * (len(x) + 1)
    print(f.format('', *x))
    for e, (k, v) in enumerate(sorted(data.items(), key=lambda it: it[1][1]), start=1):
        gv = ('{:f}'.format(g) for g in v)
        print(f.format('%s %s' % (e, k), *gv))
    # начисление "баллов", кто первее, тоиу больше - enumerate
    for e, (k, v) in enumerate(sorted(data.items(), key=lambda it: it[1][1], reverse=True), start=1):
        try: best_var[k] += e
        except KeyError: best_var[k] = e

def get_str(size: int, asc: bool, a=5, b=10, i=''):
    # ascii или ascii+noascii символы
    asc_ = ''.join(map(chr, range(256))) if asc else string.ascii_letters
    _str, ln = '', 0
    # увеличивать строку, пока размер не станет нужным
    while ln < size:
        _str += ' ' + ''.join(random.choice(asc_) for _ in range(random.randint(a, b)))  # a, b - регулировать пробелы
        ln = int(sys.getsizeof(_str)/1024)

    # инфо о строке
    ss = _str.split()
    c = len(ss)
    l, c, = len(_str), _str.count(' ')
    w = sum(len(s) for s in ss)/c
    print('\n~{}Kb, символы {} {}, {} ~ {:.3}%, сред длина слова:{:f}\nby <average>:'.format(
        ln, l, 'ascii+noascii' if asc else 'ascii', i, c/l*100, w))

    return _str


if __name__ == '__main__':
    best_var = {}
    repeat, count = 5, 1
    target = [n for n in globals() if n.startswith('var')]
    # размеры строк
    for size in 1, 1024, 1024*10:
        data = {}
        # ascii или ascii+noascii строка
        for asc in True, False:
            # кол-во пробелов
            for i, a, b in (['минимум пробелов', 20, 25],
                            ['сред пробелов', 4, 5],
                            ['много пробелов', 1, 2],
                            ['случайно пробелов', 1, 1000]):
                # сформировать строку
                _str = get_str(size, asc, a, b, i)
                # выполнить var функции
                for n in target:
                    t = timeit.Timer(globals()[n]).repeat(repeat, count)
                    data.update({n: [sum(t)/repeat, min(t), max(t)]})
                print_results(data)  # вывести результат для строки
    # вывести баллы
    print('\n'+'-'*20)
    for e, (k, v) in enumerate(sorted(best_var.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1], reverse=True), start=1):
        print('{} место {:<5} - {} баллов'.format(e, k, v))
```

out:

```
~1Kb, символы 989 ascii+noascii, минимум пробелов ~ 4.65%, сред длина слова:19.347826
by <average>:
              average      min          max         
 1 var8       0.000004     0.000003     0.000005    
 2 var7       0.000006     0.000006     0.000008    
 3 var3       0.000022     0.000022     0.000025    
 4 var2       0.000063     0.000054     0.000085    
 5 var1       0.000124     0.000117     0.000134    
 6 var4       0.000172     0.000157     0.000187    
 7 var9       0.000264     0.000157     0.000401    
 8 var6       0.000235     0.000213     0.000295    
 9 var10      0.000311     0.000279     0.000343    
 10 var5      0.000439     0.000389     0.000494    

~1Kb, символы 989 ascii+noascii, сред пробелов ~ 18.4%, сред длина слова:4.252747
by <average>:
              average      min          max         
 1 var8       0.000004     0.000003     0.000004    
 2 var7       0.000013     0.000012     0.000015    
 3 var3       0.000031     0.000030     0.000033    
 4 var2       0.000072     0.000068     0.000081    
 5 var1       0.000115     0.000111     0.000130    
 6 var9       0.000145     0.000138     0.000164    
 7 var4       0.000150     0.000143     0.000165    
 8 var6       0.000235     0.000213     0.000259    
 9 var10      0.000267     0.000258     0.000283    
 10 var5      0.000417     0.000385     0.000468    

~1Kb, символы 987 ascii+noascii, много пробелов ~ 40.7%, сред длина слова:1.375622
by <average>:
              average      min          max         
 1 var8       0.000005     0.000004     0.000006    
 2 var7       0.000019     0.000018     0.000020    
 3 var3       0.000038     0.000035     0.000045    
 4 var2       0.000086     0.000076     0.000112    
 5 var9       0.000106     0.000098     0.000137    
 6 var1       0.000120     0.000104     0.000153    
 7 var4       0.000119     0.000117     0.000123    
 8 var10      0.000193     0.000178     0.000228    
 9 var6       0.000228     0.000216     0.000264    
 10 var5      0.000409     0.000386     0.000447    

~1Kb, символы 1491 ascii+noascii, случайно пробелов ~ 0.738%, сред длина слова:127.818182
by <average>:
              average      min          max         
 1 var8       0.000003     0.000003     0.000004    
 2 var7       0.000004     0.000004     0.000005    
 3 var3       0.000027     0.000026     0.000029    
 4 var2       0.000078     0.000068     0.000109    
 5 var1       0.000207     0.000201     0.000223    
 6 var9       0.000247     0.000229     0.000274    
 7 var4       0.000261     0.000235     0.000312    
 8 var6       0.000344     0.000319     0.000381    
 9 var10      0.000459     0.000439     0.000503    
 10 var5      0.000605     0.000572     0.000640    

~1Kb, символы 1007 ascii, минимум пробелов ~ 4.27%, сред длина слова:22.418605
by <average>:
              average      min          max         
 1 var8       0.000003     0.000003     0.000004    
 2 var7       0.000006     0.000005     0.000007    
 3 var3       0.000009     0.000008     0.000010    
 4 var2       0.000045     0.000040     0.000056    
 5 var1       0.000139     0.000116     0.000164    
 6 var9       0.000168     0.000151     0.000187    
 7 var4       0.000161     0.000151     0.000195    
 8 var6       0.000229     0.000214     0.000275    
 9 var10      0.000303     0.000299     0.000314    
 10 var5      0.000406     0.000383     0.000435    

~1Kb, символы 1001 ascii, сред пробелов ~ 18.0%, сред длина слова:4.561111
by <average>:
              average      min          max         
 1 var8       0.000003     0.000003     0.000004    
 2 var7       0.000012     0.000011     0.000012    
 3 var3       0.000019     0.000018     0.000020    
 4 var2       0.000064     0.000056     0.000091    
 5 var1       0.000117     0.000105     0.000148    
 6 var9       0.000142     0.000131     0.000177    
 7 var4       0.000151     0.000138     0.000182    
 8 var6       0.000222     0.000213     0.000257    
 9 var10      0.000265     0.000253     0.000302    
 10 var5      0.000409     0.000382     0.000451    

~1Kb, символы 1001 ascii, много пробелов ~ 40.0%, сред длина слова:1.502500
by <average>:
              average      min          max         
 1 var8       0.000004     0.000004     0.000005    
 2 var7       0.000021     0.000020     0.000023    
 3 var3       0.000033     0.000031     0.000036    
 4 var2       0.000077     0.000076     0.000081    
 5 var1       0.000111     0.000099     0.000139    
 6 var9       0.000110     0.000104     0.000138    
 7 var4       0.000123     0.000123     0.000124    
 8 var10      0.000207     0.000197     0.000231    
 9 var6       0.000234     0.000225     0.000257    
 10 var5      0.000419     0.000408     0.000441    

~1Kb, символы 1357 ascii, случайно пробелов ~ 0.221%, сред длина слова:451.333333
by <average>:
              average      min          max         
 1 var8       0.000002     0.000002     0.000003    
 2 var7       0.000003     0.000003     0.000004    
 3 var3       0.000004     0.000004     0.000005    
 4 var2       0.000047     0.000044     0.000051    
 5 var1       0.000161     0.000150     0.000198    
 6 var9       0.000217     0.000208     0.000246    
 7 var4       0.000221     0.000210     0.000264    
 8 var6       0.000302     0.000287     0.000339    
 9 var10      0.000449     0.000418     0.000470    
 10 var5      0.000557     0.000517     0.000579    

~1024Kb, символы 1048550 ascii+noascii, минимум пробелов ~ 4.62%, сред длина слова:19.736590
by <average>:
              average      min          max         
 1 var8       0.001648     0.001501     0.001976    
 2 var7       0.004883     0.004693     0.005125    
 3 var3       0.020394     0.019550     0.021583    
 4 var2       0.062164     0.060919     0.063352    
 5 var1       0.144303     0.135828     0.159222    
 6 var9       0.178833     0.176592     0.182050    
 7 var4       0.199833     0.196554     0.205470    
 8 var6       0.251038     0.246122     0.259824    
 9 var10      0.335161     0.331631     0.338379    
 10 var5      0.452639     0.443677     0.466173    

~1024Kb, символы 1048543 ascii+noascii, сред пробелов ~ 18.5%, сред длина слова:4.216881
by <average>:
              average      min          max         
 1 var8       0.002237     0.002042     0.002632    
 2 var7       0.011823     0.011346     0.012312    
 3 var3       0.033965     0.032902     0.034526    
 4 var2       0.084031     0.081243     0.087056    
 5 var1       0.127829     0.126500     0.129401    
 6 var9       0.158385     0.154023     0.162586    
 7 var4       0.180536     0.178501     0.182689    
 8 var6       0.250811     0.246209     0.255653    
 9 var10      0.285592     0.283369     0.288488    
 10 var5      0.454162     0.445657     0.470404    

~1024Kb, символы 1048539 ascii+noascii, много пробелов ~ 40.2%, сред длина слова:1.422101
by <average>:
              average      min          max         
 1 var8       0.002705     0.002559     0.002869    
 2 var7       0.019173     0.018673     0.019514    
 3 var3       0.044011     0.041986     0.045685    
 4 var2       0.092004     0.090061     0.095451    
 5 var1       0.117086     0.112984     0.122531    
 6 var9       0.116413     0.113467     0.120848    
 7 var4       0.152174     0.150377     0.154708    
 8 var10      0.209933     0.203534     0.214091    
 9 var6       0.255368     0.251358     0.260667    
 10 var5      0.449192     0.448205     0.450778    

~1024Kb, символы 1048798 ascii+noascii, случайно пробелов ~ 0.585%, сред длина слова:162.651182
by <average>:
              average      min          max         
 1 var8       0.000781     0.000757     0.000808    
 2 var7       0.002128     0.001986     0.002363    
 3 var3       0.014138     0.013806     0.014757    
 4 var2       0.056218     0.054372     0.059153    
 5 var1       0.141643     0.137505     0.146517    
 6 var9       0.188750     0.184148     0.193892    
 7 var4       0.205695     0.201427     0.209657    
 8 var6       0.265923     0.258749     0.275960    
 9 var10      0.344992     0.331897     0.352945    
 10 var5      0.458320     0.446551     0.482520    

~1024Kb, символы 1048574 ascii, минимум пробелов ~ 4.26%, сред длина слова:22.496930
by <average>:
              average      min          max         
 1 var8       0.001505     0.001434     0.001623    
 2 var7       0.004558     0.004468     0.004666    
 3 var3       0.006457     0.006183     0.006700    
 4 var2       0.045978     0.045481     0.046309    
 5 var1       0.136627     0.132597     0.143002    
 6 var9       0.180005     0.172714     0.186334    
 7 var4       0.195560     0.193381     0.200404    
 8 var6       0.243767     0.238857     0.246907    
 9 var10      0.333131     0.328723     0.344105    
 10 var5      0.439651     0.432095     0.446828    

~1024Kb, символы 1048554 ascii, сред пробелов ~ 18.2%, сред длина слова:4.498592
by <average>:
              average      min          max         
 1 var8       0.002240     0.002156     0.002484    
 2 var7       0.011550     0.011379     0.011812    
 3 var3       0.019653     0.018650     0.020899    
 4 var2       0.064917     0.063636     0.066031    
 5 var1       0.122076     0.120085     0.123909    
 6 var9       0.151459     0.148554     0.153874    
 7 var4       0.178413     0.175546     0.183586    
 8 var6       0.244974     0.243148     0.246615    
 9 var10      0.283760     0.279793     0.286557    
 10 var5      0.444185     0.440670     0.446956    

~1024Kb, символы 1048552 ascii, много пробелов ~ 40.0%, сред длина слова:1.500690
by <average>:
              average      min          max         
 1 var8       0.002606     0.002548     0.002662    
 2 var7       0.019870     0.019037     0.020380    
 3 var3       0.033964     0.032878     0.036014    
 4 var2       0.086213     0.085267     0.087383    
 5 var1       0.111353     0.109741     0.114724    
 6 var9       0.112563     0.111011     0.114503    
 7 var4       0.150361     0.147747     0.152117    
 8 var10      0.210284     0.209237     0.210916    
 9 var6       0.250411     0.247752     0.257964    
 10 var5      0.453721     0.449482     0.457010    

~1024Kb, символы 1048782 ascii, случайно пробелов ~ 0.197%, сред длина слова:506.147969
by <average>:
              average      min          max         
 1 var8       0.000675     0.000646     0.000688    
 2 var7       0.001583     0.001502     0.001764    
 3 var3       0.002933     0.002437     0.003270    
 4 var2       0.044154     0.043674     0.045305    
 5 var1       0.135097     0.134006     0.136763    
 6 var9       0.192888     0.190767     0.194671    
 7 var4       0.200822     0.199586     0.203285    
 8 var6       0.242871     0.240081     0.246809    
 9 var10      0.352606     0.344659     0.360171    
 10 var5      0.440387     0.433437     0.446731    

~10240Kb, символы 10485723 ascii+noascii, минимум пробелов ~ 4.63%, сред длина слова:19.713800
by <average>:
              average      min          max         
 1 var8       0.015642     0.015346     0.016142    
 2 var7       0.050325     0.049391     0.052610    
 3 var3       0.210275     0.209163     0.212247    
 4 var2       0.676338     0.669641     0.682927    
 5 var1       1.389115     1.368039     1.398386    
 6 var9       1.821897     1.803700     1.843339    
 7 var4       1.994729     1.989236     2.000370    
 8 var6       2.491980     2.478701     2.511737    
 9 var10      3.274745     3.246427     3.296595    
 10 var5      4.452530     4.420066     4.492152    

~10240Kb, символы 10485725 ascii+noascii, сред пробелов ~ 18.5%, сред длина слова:4.214989
by <average>:
              average      min          max         
 1 var8       0.022165     0.021553     0.022992    
 2 var7       0.119701     0.117069     0.122963    
 3 var3       0.363989     0.359079     0.367310    
 4 var2       0.885933     0.878938     0.891297    
 5 var1       1.294802     1.277431     1.311001    
 6 var9       1.617785     1.611125     1.622048    
 7 var4       1.818916     1.810579     1.830913    
 8 var6       2.547398     2.510476     2.582020    
 9 var10      2.828624     2.809815     2.854437    
 10 var5      4.480788     4.459377     4.500519    

~10240Kb, символы 10485725 ascii+noascii, много пробелов ~ 40.2%, сред длина слова:1.421055
by <average>:
              average      min          max         
 1 var8       0.028091     0.027061     0.030288    
 2 var7       0.196943     0.195305     0.199955    
 3 var3       0.474881     0.461343     0.482662    
 4 var2       1.008938     0.997040     1.027451    
 5 var1       1.161058     1.136066     1.171011    
 6 var9       1.215664     1.164296     1.233138    
 7 var4       1.543121     1.527249     1.553288    
 8 var10      2.080153     2.052537     2.101885    
 9 var6       2.522675     2.515321     2.530619    
 10 var5      4.563395     4.491082     4.623651    

~10240Kb, символы 10486201 ascii+noascii, случайно пробелов ~ 0.587%, сред длина слова:162.080908
by <average>:
              average      min          max         
 1 var8       0.007789     0.007583     0.008320    
 2 var7       0.019142     0.018552     0.019879    
 3 var3       0.165453     0.162585     0.168957    
 4 var2       0.615963     0.611608     0.620655    
 5 var1       1.440067     1.421817     1.455080    
 6 var9       1.899005     1.880525     1.917015    
 7 var4       2.041620     2.014194     2.117118    
 8 var6       2.530870     2.444620     2.644582    
 9 var10      3.375323     3.322056     3.430780    
 10 var5      4.403470     4.363339     4.462611    

~10240Kb, символы 10485746 ascii, минимум пробелов ~ 4.26%, сред длина слова:22.500840
by <average>:
              average      min          max         
 1 var8       0.015668     0.015235     0.016608    
 2 var7       0.045992     0.045382     0.046675    
 3 var3       0.076034     0.074871     0.076558    
 4 var2       0.534177     0.530063     0.538483    
 5 var1       1.335994     1.329036     1.342069    
 6 var9       1.802360     1.792313     1.820512    
 7 var4       1.954488     1.942886     1.964544    
 8 var6       2.426299     2.420271     2.436364    
 9 var10      3.302575     3.286494     3.319168    
 10 var5      4.434964     4.352420     4.603488    

~10240Kb, символы 10485737 ascii, сред пробелов ~ 18.2%, сред длина слова:4.499947
by <average>:
              average      min          max         
 1 var8       0.021396     0.020741     0.021759    
 2 var7       0.114626     0.113296     0.115541    
 3 var3       0.226316     0.222824     0.229988    
 4 var2       0.728126     0.721727     0.737932    
 5 var1       1.257480     1.250478     1.265838    
 6 var9       1.558776     1.552425     1.565449    
 7 var4       1.782327     1.774427     1.787684    
 8 var6       2.444034     2.425254     2.466785    
 9 var10      2.867036     2.849253     2.882571    
 10 var5      4.398630     4.370555     4.425208    

~10240Kb, символы 10485735 ascii, много пробелов ~ 40.0%, сред длина слова:1.499905
by <average>:
              average      min          max         
 1 var8       0.026567     0.026069     0.027204    
 2 var7       0.192424     0.190171     0.193983    
 3 var3       0.377138     0.371293     0.384058    
 4 var2       0.933870     0.931780     0.936487    
 5 var1       1.130904     1.126566     1.141807    
 6 var9       1.166317     1.150050     1.172436    
 7 var4       1.516546     1.510337     1.525137    
 8 var10      2.116518     2.085666     2.135315    
 9 var6       2.488669     2.479040     2.502971    
 10 var5      4.465629     4.457348     4.473298    

~10240Kb, символы 10485820 ascii, случайно пробелов ~ 0.198%, сред длина слова:502.932141
by <average>:
              average      min          max         
 1 var8       0.007237     0.006813     0.007651    
 2 var7       0.016183     0.015791     0.016414    
 3 var3       0.030802     0.029833     0.031738    
 4 var2       0.468537     0.457903     0.477776    
 5 var1       1.375179     1.357010     1.388190    
 6 var9       1.879247     1.867879     1.896920    
 7 var4       2.016457     1.990694     2.060548    
 8 var6       2.413361     2.397260     2.420363    
 9 var10      3.465412     3.430199     3.499782    
 10 var5      4.380763     4.351999     4.431059    

--------------------
1 место var8  - 240 баллов
2 место var7  - 216 баллов
3 место var3  - 192 баллов
4 место var2  - 168 баллов
5 место var1  - 143 баллов
6 место var9  - 121 баллов
7 место var4  - 96 баллов
8 место var6  - 66 баллов
9 место var10 - 54 баллов
10 место var5  - 24 баллов
```

Comment: Не имеет смысла два десятка цифр после запятой показывать. Точность измерения явно хуже. Ограничьтесь парой/тройкой значащих цифр, если лучшей оценки нет. Посмотрите как `python -mtimeit` реализован. Было бы интересно сравнить результаты для коротких строк (как в вопросе), для строк с 1К, 1М, 1G символов, в которых пробелы часты/редки, есть/отсутствуют не-ascii пробелы/другие символы.

Comment: снова: больше цифр, не значит лучше (спросите себя как это поможет читателю, какие выводы?). 1- ([реализация timeit не рекомендует ничего кроме min использовать (уберите average, max колонки)—если объяснение не ясно, спросите, я переведу](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9581189b1cdf77ce3eff8342c0192f3ecdfc951f/Lib/timeit.py#L193-L202). 2-  Я упомянул не-ascii случай, потому что многие решения не работают в этом случае, например,  `s='1 2'`. Если решение неверно, то не важно как быстро оно неправильный результат получает—их следует исключить из сравнения для не-ascii.

Comment: 3- Я упомянул тестирование c 1G символами, чтобы ясно показать почему O(1) методы (постоянная память, не зависящая от ввода) имеют преимущество (`count()` над `replace()` для ascii случая или `finditer()` решение имеет смысл для не-ascii случая, для строк (или mmap многогигабайтных файлов) настолько больших что дорого `.split()` вызывать, который список создаёт. Сравнение 1M vs. 10M в этом случае ничего не даёт. Разные размеры стоит в результатах приводить, если они что-то содержательное подтверждают. Есть и другие замечания (я могу продолжить, если хотите)

Answer (score 3):

В лоб:

```
len = 0
s = '99 99 99 99'
for с in s:
  if с != ' ':
    len += 1
print len
```

> 8

Функционально-извращенно:

```
s = '99 99 99 99'
print sum(map(lambda c: int(not(c == ' ')) , s))
```

> 8

или

```
sum(map(lambda c: 1 if c != ' ' else 0, s))
```

Comment: `reduce` лучше подойдёт чем `sum ( map )`

Comment: @Arnial `reduce` тут не нужен: `sum(c != ' ' for c in s)` или `sum(map(str.isspace, s))` (последнее поддерживает произвольные пробельные символы) если в этом ключе решение хочется.