# Как убрать все Unicode символы из строки?

Tags: python, unicode

Как убрать все Unicode символы из строки ?

Comment: что вы подразумеваете под "unicode символы"? Можете привести пример?

Comment: возможно, один из ответов на https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689795/how-can-i-remove-non-ascii-characters-but-leave-periods-and-spaces-using-python вам поможет

Comment: MaxU  , https://unicode-table.com/ru/#telugu , любой unicode символ

Comment: Любой существующий для компьютера символ автоматически является unicode-символом. Любая строка автоматически состоит из unicode-символов целиком. Вывод: для решения вашей задачи ничего делать не нужно :)

Comment: @SaharVkusni, включая [latin1](https://unicode-table.com/ru/#basic-latin), [кирилицу](https://unicode-table.com/ru/#cyrillic), etc. - т.е. любой символ принадлежащий Unicode??

Comment: @andreymal, если быть точным, то для решения задачи надо заменить все строки на пустые строки... ;)

Comment: Unicode — это, грубо говоря, всего лишь огромный список символов, в который входят в том числе символы любой другой кодировки. Так что да, для любой кодировки `... включая latin1, кириллицу` (Windows-1251, КОИ8-Р и др.) `, etc` найдётся соответствие в Unicode. Поэтому вас и просят уточнить, что же вы имеете в виду.

Comment: @Arhad: С точки зрения Питона, latin1, cp1251, koi8-r, utf-8 итд кодировки определяют как текст (Unicodу строка -- последовательность Unicode codepoints) в байты превратить (набор чисел от 0 до 255): `bytestring = unicode_text.encode(encoding)`. То есть само понятие текста синонимично с Unicode. И в обратную сторону: последовательность байт можно как текст интерпретировать, применив кодировку: `unicode_text = bytestring.decode(encoding)` (стоит заметить, что одна и та же последовательность байт может разный текст  представлять (или вообще никакой -- картинка, архив) в зависмости от кодировки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Регулярные выражения**

```
import re
string = 'привет world'
result = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]', '', string)
```

**строка -> байты -> строка**

```
'hello мир'.encode('ascii', errors='ignore').decode()
```

**list и join**

```
string = 'привет, как дела?'
result = ''.join([char for char in string if ord(char) >= 32 and ord(char) <= 126])
```

**filter и join**

```
string = 'привет!'
result = ''.join(filter(lambda char: ord(char) >= 32 and ord(char) <= 126, string))
```

Comment: ASCII это подмножество юникода и по совместительству валидный UTF-8 :)

Answer (score 1):

Строка в Питоне является неизменяемой последовательностью Unicode символов. Поэтому если на вопрос буквально отвечать, то чтобы убрать из строки все Unicode символы (не важно соответствуют они какой-нибудь букве или нет), достаточно переменную пустой строке присвоить.

Если ваш вопрос «как не ascii символы убрать из строки»:

```
>>> 'ascii кириллица'.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode()
'ascii '
```

Связанный вопрос: [Как удалить все пробелы из строки в Python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/359110/23044)