# Удаление скрытых символов

Tags: python, python-3.x, текст

Как можно удалить скрытые символы из строки? Длина строки в базе данных отличается от строки в pythone. Скорее всего это символы \t \r \n

Comment: Регулярным выражением, смотрите мета-символ `\S`.

Comment: re.sub('[\t\r\n]', '', text)

Comment: Строго говоря, ни один из символов `\t` `\r` `\n` не является скрытым и прекрасно палится своим поведением при выводе. Может, лучше сделаете `print(repr(строка))` для каждой из ваших проблемных строк и покажете результат нам?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как удалить все пробелы из строки в Python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/359110/23044)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Удаление `\t`, `\r` и `\n`:

```
import re

text = '''
Hel lo  Wor

    ld  
!
'''
print(repr(text))  # '\nHel\tlo  \t\tWor\n\n\tld\t\n  !\n'

new_text = re.sub('[\t\r\n]', '', text)
print(new_text)  # Hello World!
```